# There are always line breaks after an enum declaration

Tags: c++, enums, clang-format

I have the following `BraceWrapping` options:

```
BraceWrapping:
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterStruct: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  AfterControlStatement: "Never"
  AfterFunction: false
  AfterNamespace: false
  AfterUnion: false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch: false
  BeforeElse: false
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile: false
```

However, clang-format always inserts a new line after an enum:

```
enum class event_flags : std::uint8_t
{
    running = 1 << 0,
    executed = 1 << 1,
};
```

I want it to be like this:

```
enum class event_flags : std::uint8_t {
    running = 1 << 0,
    executed = 1 << 1,
};
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Fwiw: I get the formatting like you want it even if I replace the whole `BraceWrapping` section in my `.clang-format` with your section - so I'm guessing that it's something else that controls this behavior. I can't quite figure out what though. Perhaps you should include the whole `.clang-format` file? It's not more than ~180 lines or so I guess?

Comment: @TedLyngmo all other rules are working perfectly fine, so I doubt it has something to do with my clag-format file.

Comment: If it doesn't have to do with something in your `.clang-format` file, where does the above section `BraceWrapping` come from? As I said, I put your section, just as you showed it, in my `.clang-format` file and it still formats it like you want it. Here's my [`.clang-format`](https://pastebin.com/uwJVvbw8) (clang-format 13.0.0) if you'd like to test it to see if it makes the above formatting better.  You may need to remove some lines if you have an older `clang-format` binary though. If you paste yours at pastebin I can check on my side at the same time.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, Here is my `.clang-format` file content: https://pastebin.com/YMR2iEs9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one option I could find that seems to fix this formatting for you is outside the `BraceWrapping` section and that is setting

```
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
```

even though the description of that option doesn't mention it:

`true`:

```
enum { A, B } myEnum;
```

`false`:

```
enum {
  A,
  B
} myEnum;
```

Comment: The more I look at my answer, the more it looks like exploiting a bug - but it works :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I deleted the line `AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine`, and it works now how I want :)
I guess I have to do without single line enums :D

Comment: @Raildex :-) You're welcome! It may be worth filing a bug report. I would expect `AfterEnum: false`, like you have, to do the trick.

Comment: I had this bug in clang-format-12, but I tried it in clang-format-16 and it seems fixed. I don't know exactly which version fixed it, since I only have these two versions here.